# Insert Performance: Use HashSet at begin vs use ArrayList at begin and use hashset to remove duplicate at the end

Tags: java

Which one should be faster? I need to insert element quickly and also remove duplicates.

Code example:

```
List catNames = new ArrayList();
for(Cat cat: cats){
catNames.add(nameTheCat(cat));
}
new HashSet(catNames); // remove duplicates finally
```

vs

```
HashSet catNames = new HashSet();
for(Cat cat: cats){
catNames.add(nameTheCat(cat));
}
```

Comment: Second will be faster, In the first one you create one redundant object in Heap, which takes time

Comment: @SchiduLuca Hashset is also using list (linked list in a hashmap) + hashcode calculation

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet (creating the `List` first) can be wasteful (both in memory and time) if there are many duplicates, since you are going to eliminate the duplicates later.

Therefore, it makes more sense to use the second snippet, and add the elements directly to the `Set`.

EDIT: after changing your question, you can shorten your code by using `Stream`s:

```
Set<String> catNames = cats.map(cat->nameTheCat(cat)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```